# Is it possible to conditionally trigger a Github -> Slack push event webhook?

Tags: github, slack

I'd like to setup a Github -> Slack webhook, so that when a commit with a certain message is pushed to a given branch on the Github repository, a message is posted to a Slack channel.

I've checked the documentation, and I've found that one can apply fancy formatting to a webhook payload, however, I couldn't find any way to apply a conditional (ie. "discard payload if the payload field doesn't contain the string XYZ").

Is this possible?